# Keeping AOSP fork up-to-date

Tags: android, android-source, repo, git-fork

I have forked AOSP (all repos) from the Google's repositories, and I want to:

1. Keep a copy with my changes in my own Git repositories (for instance, `private`)
2. Periodically pull changes from Google's repositories (for instance, `aosp`)

How should I correctly do it with `repo`? Repo manifest can contain multiple remotes, but how can I specify, that I want to use `aosp` only for pulling, and `private` for both pushing and pulling?

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36393610/497132) answer, but it doesn't clarify how to sync the forked repository with the original one (and it covers only the case when I'm forking a single repository, not the whole AOSP code).

Comment: How do your forked the AOSP? Where is your repositories? In the github or the private server?

Comment: @Yong with `repo` to my local machine (not by forking on the GitHub itself), then I've created corresponding private repos on GitHub and now I want to push the code there

Comment: 1. sync code from aosp; 2. use repo forall to push synced code to github: repo forall -c "pwd;git push private remotes/aosp/master:refs/heads/master". So the aosp master will be put in your private github. And you should create an new branch for development. Don't use the branches in aosp, or it will be conflict. A better way is to creating branch with an prefix. For example  my/master, or my-master.